# Generating HAR with Watir / NetExport / Firebug

Tags: ruby, selenium, firebug, watir, netexport

I am attempting to generate a HAR file using NetExport 0.8, Firebug 1.9.2, and watir-webdriver 0.8.0.  Nothing fancy, here's the code:

```
    require 'watir-webdriver'

    def setup
      profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new

      profile.add_extension '/Users/user/Downloads/firebug-1.9.2.xpi'
      profile.add_extension '/Users/user/Downloads/netExport-0.8.xpi'

      profile['app.update.enabled'] = false

      profile['extensions.firebug.currentVersion'] = '1.9.2'
      profile['extensions.firebug.showFirstrunPage'] = false
      profile['extensions.firebug.allPagesActivation'] = 'on'
      profile['extensions.firebug.onByDefault'] = true
      profile['extensions.firebug.framePosition'] = 'detached'
      profile['extensions.firebug.defaultPanelName'] = 'net'
      profile['extensions.firebug.net.enableSites'] = true

      profile['extensions.firebug.netexport.alwaysEnableAutoExport'] = true
      profile['extensions.firebug.netexport.autoExportToFile'] = true
      profile['extensions.firebug.netexport.autoExportToServer'] = false
      profile['extensions.firebug.netexport.showPreview'] = false
      profile['extensions.firebug.extensions.firebug.netexport.defaultLogDir'] = File.expand_path File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/har'

      @driver = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => profile
    end
```

I'm importing this code into an IRB session and running setup.  The Firefox instance loads up, and I can see all my preferences are set correctly in about:config.

Here's the IRB session with -d, just after I run setup:

```
    2.1.3 :002 > setup
    /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/capabilities.rb:224: warning: method redefined; discarding old proxy=
    /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/capabilities.rb:47: warning: previous definition of proxy= was here
    /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:125: warning: method redefined; discarding old proxy
    {:extension=>"firebug-1.9.2"}
    Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1334 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - /var/folders/2g/h_9hr8m12xs12nwxbl0mts7r0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20150916-40722-n7id7n/extensions/firebug@software.joehewitt.com
    Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1334 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - /var/folders/2g/h_9hr8m12xs12nwxbl0mts7r0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20150916-40722-n7id7n/extensions/firebug@software.joehewitt.com
    Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1454 - No such file or directory @ unlink_internal - /var/folders/2g/h_9hr8m12xs12nwxbl0mts7r0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20150916-40722-n7id7n/extensions/firebug@software.joehewitt.com
    {:extension=>"netExport-0.8"}
    Exception `Errno::EINVAL' at /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/rubyzip-1.1.6/lib/zip/central_directory.rb:159 - Invalid argument @ rb_io_seek - /Users/user/Downloads/netExport-0.8.xpi
    Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1334 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - /var/folders/2g/h_9hr8m12xs12nwxbl0mts7r0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20150916-40722-n7id7n/extensions/netexport@getfirebug.com
    Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1334 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - /var/folders/2g/h_9hr8m12xs12nwxbl0mts7r0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20150916-40722-n7id7n/extensions/netexport@getfirebug.com
    Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1454 - No such file or directory @ unlink_internal - /var/folders/2g/h_9hr8m12xs12nwxbl0mts7r0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20150916-40722-n7id7n/extensions/netexport@getfirebug.com
    Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:247 - File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - /var/folders/2g/h_9hr8m12xs12nwxbl0mts7r0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20150916-40722-n7id7n/extensions
    {:extension=>:webdriver}
    Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1334 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - /var/folders/2g/h_9hr8m12xs12nwxbl0mts7r0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20150916-40722-n7id7n/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com
    Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1334 - No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - /var/folders/2g/h_9hr8m12xs12nwxbl0mts7r0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20150916-40722-n7id7n/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com
    Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1454 - No such file or directory @ unlink_internal - /var/folders/2g/h_9hr8m12xs12nwxbl0mts7r0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20150916-40722-n7id7n/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com
    Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:247 - File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - /var/folders/2g/h_9hr8m12xs12nwxbl0mts7r0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20150916-40722-n7id7n/extensions
    Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1454 - No such file or directory @ unlink_internal - /var/folders/2g/h_9hr8m12xs12nwxbl0mts7r0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20150916-40722-n7id7n/.parentlock
    Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1454 - No such file or directory @ unlink_internal - /var/folders/2g/h_9hr8m12xs12nwxbl0mts7r0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20150916-40722-n7id7n/parent.lock
    Exception `Errno::ENOENT' at /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:1454 - No such file or directory @ unlink_internal - /var/folders/2g/h_9hr8m12xs12nwxbl0mts7r0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20150916-40722-n7id7n/extensions.cache
    Exception `LoadError' at /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55 - cannot load such file -- oj
    Exception `LoadError' at /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:141 - cannot load such file -- oj
    Exception `LoadError' at /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55 - cannot load such file -- yajl
    Exception `LoadError' at /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:141 - cannot load such file -- yajl
    Exception `LoadError' at /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55 - cannot load such file -- jrjackson
    Exception `LoadError' at /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:141 - cannot load such file -- jrjackson
    Using Ext extension for JSON.
    /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/childprocess-0.5.5/lib/childprocess/unix/fork_exec_process.rb:43: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
    #<ChildProcess::Unix::ForkExecProcess:0x007fe6c1009768 @args=["/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin", "-no-remote", "-foreground"], @started=true, @exit_code=nil, @io=#<ChildProcess::Unix::IO:0x007fe6c10096c8 @stdout=#<IO:<STDOUT>>, @stderr=#<IO:<STDERR>>>, @cwd=nil, @detach=false, @duplex=false, @leader=false, @environment={}, @pid=40727> : [{:pid=>nil, :status=>nil}]
    #<ChildProcess::Unix::ForkExecProcess:0x007fe6c1009768 @args=["/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin", "-no-remote", "-foreground"], @started=true, @exit_code=nil, @io=#<ChildProcess::Unix::IO:0x007fe6c10096c8 @stdout=#<IO:<STDOUT>>, @stderr=#<IO:<STDERR>>>, @cwd=nil, @detach=false, @duplex=false, @leader=false, @environment={}, @pid=40727> : [{:pid=>nil, :status=>nil}]
    Exception `IO::EINPROGRESSWaitWritable' at /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_poller.rb:82 - Operation now in progress - connect(2) would block
    Exception `Errno::ECONNREFUSED' at /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_poller.rb:82 - Connection refused - connect(2) for 127.0.0.1:7055
    ["127.0.0.1", 7055]
    Exception `IO::EINPROGRESSWaitWritable' at /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_poller.rb:82 - Operation now in progress - connect(2) would block
    Exception `Errno::ECONNREFUSED' at /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_poller.rb:82 - Connection refused - connect(2) for 127.0.0.1:7055
    ["127.0.0.1", 7055]
    Exception `IO::EINPROGRESSWaitWritable' at /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_poller.rb:82 - Operation now in progress - connect(2) would block
    Exception `Errno::ECONNREFUSED' at /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_poller.rb:82 - Connection refused - connect(2) for 127.0.0.1:7055
    ["127.0.0.1", 7055]
    Exception `IO::EINPROGRESSWaitWritable' at /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_poller.rb:82 - Operation now in progress - connect(2) would block
    Exception `Errno::ECONNREFUSED' at /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_poller.rb:82 - Connection refused - connect(2) for 127.0.0.1:7055
    ["127.0.0.1", 7055]
    1442434466001 addons.manager  DEBUG Application has been upgraded
    1442434466016 addons.manager  DEBUG Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm: ["XPIProvider"]
    1442434466017 addons.manager  DEBUG Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/LightweightThemeManager.jsm: ["LightweightThemeManager"]
    1442434466019 addons.manager  DEBUG Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/GMPProvider.jsm
    1442434466021 addons.manager  DEBUG Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/PluginProvider.jsm
    1442434466022 addons.manager  DEBUG Starting provider: XPIProvider
    1442434466022 addons.xpi  DEBUG startup
    1442434466022 addons.xpi  INFO  Mapping firebug@software.joehewitt.com to /var/folders/2g/h_9hr8m12xs12nwxbl0mts7r0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20150916-40722-n7id7n/extensions/firebug@software.joehewitt.com
    1442434466023 addons.xpi  INFO  Mapping fxdriver@googlecode.com to /var/folders/2g/h_9hr8m12xs12nwxbl0mts7r0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20150916-40722-n7id7n/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com
    1442434466023 addons.xpi  INFO  Mapping netexport@getfirebug.com to /var/folders/2g/h_9hr8m12xs12nwxbl0mts7r0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20150916-40722-n7id7n/extensions/netexport@getfirebug.com
    1442434466023 addons.xpi  INFO  Mapping {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} to /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
    1442434466024 addons.xpi  DEBUG Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
    1442434466024 addons.xpi  DEBUG checkForChanges
    1442434466025 addons.xpi  DEBUG Loaded add-on state from prefs: {}
    1442434466025 addons.xpi  DEBUG New add-on firebug@software.joehewitt.com in app-profile
    1442434466025 addons.xpi  DEBUG getModTime: Recursive scan of firebug@software.joehewitt.com
    1442434466042 addons.xpi  DEBUG New add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com in app-profile
    1442434466042 addons.xpi  DEBUG getModTime: Recursive scan of fxdriver@googlecode.com
    1442434466045 addons.xpi  DEBUG New add-on netexport@getfirebug.com in app-profile
    1442434466046 addons.xpi  DEBUG getModTime: Recursive scan of netexport@getfirebug.com
    1442434466048 addons.xpi  DEBUG New add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} in app-global
    1442434466048 addons.xpi  DEBUG getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
    1442434466048 addons.xpi  DEBUG getInstallState changed: true, state: {"app-profile":{"firebug@software.joehewitt.com":{"d":"/var/folders/2g/h_9hr8m12xs12nwxbl0mts7r0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20150916-40722-n7id7n/extensions/firebug@software.joehewitt.com","st":1442434463000,"mt":1442434463000},"fxdriver@googlecode.com":{"d":"/var/folders/2g/h_9hr8m12xs12nwxbl0mts7r0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20150916-40722-n7id7n/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com","st":1442434464000,"mt":1442434464000},"netexport@getfirebug.com":{"d":"/var/folders/2g/h_9hr8m12xs12nwxbl0mts7r0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20150916-40722-n7id7n/extensions/netexport@getfirebug.com","st":1442434463000,"mt":1442434463000}},"app-global":{"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","st":1440078979000,"mt":1440078977000}}}
    1442434466056 addons.xpi-utils  DEBUG Opening XPI database /var/folders/2g/h_9hr8m12xs12nwxbl0mts7r0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20150916-40722-n7id7n/extensions.json
    1442434466057 addons.xpi  DEBUG New add-on firebug@software.joehewitt.com installed in app-profile
    *** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
    1442434466110 addons.xpi-utils  DEBUG Make addon app-profile:firebug@software.joehewitt.com visible
    1442434466111 DeferredSave.extensions.json  DEBUG Save changes
    1442434466112 DeferredSave.extensions.json  DEBUG Save changes
    1442434466112 addons.xpi  DEBUG Updating XPIState for {"id":"firebug@software.joehewitt.com","syncGUID":"1cG4uBHt-D2c","location":"app-profile","version":"1.9.2","type":"extension","internalName":null,"updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"iconURL":"chrome://firebug/skin/firebug64.png","icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Firebug","description":"Web Development Evolved.","creator":"Joe Hewitt","homepageURL":"http://www.getfirebug.com/","translators":["Leszek(teo)Zyczkowski (pl-PL)","markh (nl-NL)","peter3 (sv-SE)","AlleyKat (da-DK)","Hector Zhao, lovelywcm (zh-CN)","Lukas Kucharczyk, Michal Kec (cs-CZ)","Team erweiterungen.de, ReinekeFux, Benedikt Langens, Sebastian Zartner (de-DE)","l0stintranslation, gonzalopirobutirro (it-IT)","alexxed (ro-RO)","Nicolas Martin, Franck Marcia (fr-FR)","gLes (hu-HU)","Xavi Ivars - Softcatala (ca)","gezmen (tr-TR)","eternoendless (es-AR)","Dark Preacher (ru-RU)","Tiago Oliveira, Diego de Carvalho Zimmermann, Alexandre Rapaki (pt-BR)","Juan Botias, Alvaro G. Vicario (es-ES)","Andriy Zhouck (uk-UA)","Hisateru Tanaka (ja-JP)","Mohsen Shadroo (fa-IR)","Eduard Babayan (hy-AM)","Helder Magalhaes (pt-PT)","Tomaz Macus (sl-SI)","Stoyan Stefanov, Alexander Shopov (bg)","Kristjan Bjarni Guomundsson (is-IS)","NGUYEN Manh Hung (vi-VN)","Bwah (hr-HR)","Sonickydon (el)","David Gonzales (es)","DakSrbija (sr)","bootleq (zh-TW)"],"contributors":["John J. Barton (IBM Almaden)","Jan Odvarko (Mozilla Corp.)","Max Stepanov (Aptana Inc.)","Rob Campbell (Mozilla Corp.)","Hans Hillen (Paciello Group, Mozilla)","Curtis Bartley (Mozilla Corp.)","Mike Collins (IBM Almaden)","Kevin Decker","Mike Ratcliffe (Mozilla Corp.)","Hernan Rodriguez Colmeiro","Austin Andrews","Christoph Dorn","Steven Roussey (Illuminations for Developers)","Sebastian Zartner","Harutyun Amirjanyan","Simon Lindholm"]},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"/var/folders/2g/h_9hr8m12xs12nwxbl0mts7r0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20150916-40722-n7id7n/extensions/firebug@software.joehewitt.com","installDate":1442434463000,"updateDate":1442434463000,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"bootstrap":false,"size":4870785,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":true,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":false,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"toolkit@mozilla.org","minVersion":"5.0","maxVersion":"13.*"},{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"5.0","maxVersion":"13.*"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"multiprocessCompatible":false,"signedState":0}
    1442434466112 addons.xpi  DEBUG getModTime: Recursive scan of firebug@software.joehewitt.com
    1442434466127 addons.xpi  DEBUG New add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com installed in app-profile
    1442434466132 DeferredSave.extensions.json  DEBUG Starting timer
    1442434466133 addons.xpi-utils  DEBUG Make addon app-profile:fxdriver@googlecode.com visible
    1442434466133 DeferredSave.extensions.json  DEBUG Save changes
    1442434466133 DeferredSave.extensions.json  DEBUG Save changes
    1442434466133 addons.xpi  DEBUG Updating XPIState for {"id":"fxdriver@googlecode.com","syncGUID":"45bPIA_rb0wa","location":"app-profile","version":"2.47.1","type":"extension","internalName":null,"updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Firefox WebDriver","description":"WebDriver implementation for Firefox","creator":"Simon Stewart","homepageURL":null},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"/var/folders/2g/h_9hr8m12xs12nwxbl0mts7r0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20150916-40722-n7id7n/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com","installDate":1442434464000,"updateDate":1442434464000,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"bootstrap":false,"size":8234871,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":true,"hasBinaryComponents":true,"strictCompatibility":false,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"3.0","maxVersion":"66.*"}],"targetPlatforms":[{"os":"Darwin","abi":null},{"os":"SunOS","abi":null},{"os":"FreeBSD","abi":null},{"os":"OpenBSD","abi":null},{"os":"WINNT","abi":"x86-msvc"},{"os":"Linux","abi":null}],"multiprocessCompatible":false,"signedState":0}
    1442434466133 addons.xpi  DEBUG getModTime: Recursive scan of fxdriver@googlecode.com
    1442434466136 addons.xpi  DEBUG New add-on netexport@getfirebug.com installed in app-profile
    1442434466140 addons.xpi-utils  DEBUG Make addon app-profile:netexport@getfirebug.com visible
    1442434466140 DeferredSave.extensions.json  DEBUG Save changes
    1442434466140 DeferredSave.extensions.json  DEBUG Save changes
    1442434466140 addons.xpi  DEBUG Updating XPIState for {"id":"netexport@getfirebug.com","syncGUID":"Q-Tpwf6CDBL6","location":"app-profile","version":"0.8","type":"extension","internalName":null,"updateURL":"https://getfirebug.com/releases/netexport/update.rdf","updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"NetExport","description":"Use this extension to export data from Firebug's Net panel.","creator":"Jan Odvarko","homepageURL":"http://getfirebug.com/releases/extensions.html#netexport","contributors":["Matthew Consiliens"]},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"/var/folders/2g/h_9hr8m12xs12nwxbl0mts7r0000gn/T/webdriver-profile20150916-40722-n7id7n/extensions/netexport@getfirebug.com","installDate":1442434463000,"updateDate":1442434463000,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"bootstrap":false,"size":132197,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":true,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":false,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"3.0","maxVersion":"20.*"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"multiprocessCompatible":false,"signedState":0}
    1442434466140 addons.xpi  DEBUG getModTime: Recursive scan of netexport@getfirebug.com
    1442434466141 addons.xpi  DEBUG New add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} installed in app-global
    1442434466167 addons.xpi-utils  DEBUG Make addon app-global:{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} visible
    1442434466167 DeferredSave.extensions.json  DEBUG Save changes
    1442434466167 DeferredSave.extensions.json  DEBUG Save changes
    1442434466168 addons.xpi  DEBUG Updating XPIState for {"id":"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","syncGUID":"5xW6QVmBVWep","location":"app-global","version":"40.0.2","type":"theme","internalName":"classic/1.0","updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Default","description":"The default theme.","creator":"Mozilla","homepageURL":null,"contributors":["Mozilla Contributors"]},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","installDate":1440078979000,"updateDate":1440078979000,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"skinnable":true,"size":7896,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":true,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"40.0.2","maxVersion":"40.0.2"}],"targetPlatforms":[]}
    1442434466168 addons.xpi  DEBUG getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
    1442434466169 addons.xpi  DEBUG Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
    1442434466169 addons.xpi-utils  DEBUG Updating add-on states
    1442434466170 addons.xpi-utils  DEBUG Writing add-ons list
    1442434466176 addons.manager  DEBUG Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
    1442434466177 addons.manager  DEBUG Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
    1442434466177 addons.manager  DEBUG Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
    1442434466177 addons.manager  DEBUG Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
    1442434466177 addons.manager  DEBUG Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
    1442434466177 addons.manager  DEBUG Starting provider: GMPProvider
    1442434466181 addons.manager  DEBUG Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
    1442434466181 addons.manager  DEBUG Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
    1442434466181 addons.manager  DEBUG Starting provider: PluginProvider
    1442434466182 addons.manager  DEBUG Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
    1442434466182 addons.manager  DEBUG Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
    1442434466182 addons.manager  DEBUG Completed startup sequence
    Exception `IO::EINPROGRESSWaitWritable' at /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_poller.rb:82 - Operation now in progress - connect(2) would block
    Exception `Errno::ECONNREFUSED' at /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_poller.rb:82 - Connection refused - connect(2) for 127.0.0.1:7055
    ["127.0.0.1", 7055]
    Exception `IO::EINPROGRESSWaitWritable' at /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_poller.rb:82 - Operation now in progress - connect(2) would block
    Exception `Errno::ECONNREFUSED' at /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_poller.rb:82 - Connection refused - connect(2) for 127.0.0.1:7055
    ["127.0.0.1", 7055]
    Exception `IO::EINPROGRESSWaitWritable' at /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_poller.rb:82 - Operation now in progress - connect(2) would block
    Exception `Errno::ECONNREFUSED' at /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_poller.rb:82 - Connection refused - connect(2) for 127.0.0.1:7055
    ["127.0.0.1", 7055]
    Exception `IO::EINPROGRESSWaitWritable' at /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_poller.rb:82 - Operation now in progress - connect(2) would block
    Exception `Errno::ECONNREFUSED' at /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_poller.rb:82 - Connection refused - connect(2) for 127.0.0.1:7055
    ["127.0.0.1", 7055]
    1442434467016 addons.manager  DEBUG Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
    1442434467016 addons.manager  DEBUG Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
    1442434467016 addons.manager  DEBUG Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
    1442434467080 DeferredSave.extensions.json  DEBUG Starting write
    1442434467158 addons.repository DEBUG No addons.json found.
    1442434467159 DeferredSave.addons.json  DEBUG Save changes
    1442434467163 DeferredSave.addons.json  DEBUG Starting timer
    1442434467191 addons.manager  DEBUG Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
    1442434467192 addons.manager  DEBUG Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
    1442434467192 addons.manager  DEBUG Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
    1442434467195 DeferredSave.extensions.json  DEBUG Write succeeded
    1442434467195 addons.xpi-utils  DEBUG XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 17
    Exception `IO::EINPROGRESSWaitWritable' at /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_poller.rb:82 - Operation now in progress - connect(2) would block
    Exception `Errno::ECONNREFUSED' at /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.47.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_poller.rb:82 - Connection refused - connect(2) for 127.0.0.1:7055
    ["127.0.0.1", 7055]
    1442434467224 DeferredSave.addons.json  DEBUG Starting write
    1442434467241 DeferredSave.addons.json  DEBUG Write succeeded
```

After that, I do:

```
@driver.goto "http://www.google.com"
```

Here's where I expect the HAR file, but it never shows.  Anyone else struggled with this?  I've tried various profile settings with no luck.